# Problem compiling using makefile on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

PREFACE: I gotta admit that I am a complete noob to Ubuntu and all its quirks, so please be gentle.

So I've got this program that we use for an assignment we have worked on it at the computer lab at uni - and it works perfectly there. When I try to compile on my home computer It gives me this:

```
Compiling project
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: error: 
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o: Conflicting CPU architectures 12/1
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 1
```

Before this I am just calling make in the folder where the program and the makefile is situated. Since it works fine on the school computer and I get the "Conflicting CPU architecture" error I am inclined to believe there is an error either with my Ubuntu or the GCC installation.

Ubuntu Version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

[image: Hardinfo produces this]

```
FAMILY := nrf51
SOURCES := main.c uart.c

BUILD_DIR := .build_system
LINKER_SCRIPT := $(BUILD_DIR)/linker_script.ld

GNU_PREFIX  := arm-none-eabi
CC          := $(GNU_PREFIX)-gcc
OBJCOPY     := $(GNU_PREFIX)-objcopy
OBJDUMP     := $(GNU_PREFIX)-objdump

QUIET := @

## Compiler flags
# CPU specific
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mfloat-abi=soft
# Get linker optimization for free
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections --short-enums
CFLAGS += -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin
# Good pracice
CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror -std=gnu99
# CFLAGS += -ggdb -Og / -O0 / -O3 etc

## Linker flags
CFLAGS += --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,--gc-sections -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT)
# or --specs=nano.specs -lc -lnosys

SOURCES += $(BUILD_DIR)/system_nrf51.c
SOURCES += $(BUILD_DIR)/gcc_startup_nrf51.S

.PHONY: default flash clean

default:
    @echo Compiling project
    $(QUIET)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/main.elf
    @echo Creating hex file
    $(QUIET)$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(BUILD_DIR)/main.elf $(BUILD_DIR)/main.hex

flash:
    nrfjprog -f $(FAMILY) --sectorerase --program $(BUILD_DIR)/main.hex
    nrfjprog -f $(FAMILY) --reset

erase:
    nrfjprog -f $(FAMILY) --eraseall

clean:
    $(QUIET)rm $(BUILD_DIR)/main.{elf,hex}
```

Comment: Please give us info on your compiler (gcc I think?) and the full command you are using to compile.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing arm & Intel tool-chains to compile. Post your Makefile.

Comment: GCC Version: gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
Make Version: GNU Make 4.1 Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: The makefile works fine @ the computer lab where we got Intel CPUs running the show.

Comment: There you go. Thats the makefile - that file was given to us and I have no idea what it does.

Comment: Your makefile is inflexible - it's written to work with only arm tool-chains. You need to modify so that it works on others.

Comment: How exactly did you install Cross-GCC and libraries for `arm-none-eabi` on your own computer?

Comment: @Bodo He didn't. It runs on a different machine arm tool-chains installed.

Comment: @P.P. The makefile specifies `CC := $(GNU_PREFIX)-gcc` which expands to `CC := arm-none-eabi-gcc` and the error message contains ...`/arm-none-eabi/`..., so I assume `make` actually calls `arm-none-eabi-gcc`. If `arm-none-eabi-gcc` did not exist, `make` would fail at the compile step, not at the link step.

Comment: So the assignment revolves around making software for embedded systems and we use this makefile to create a .hex file wich we flash to a micro:bit. I have both of the prerequisites which was specified by the assignment text; nrfjprog 9.8.1 and JLinkARM 6.42C - so I dont think I am lacking anything in that aspect?

Comment: The machines in our lab runs the same Ubuntu OS and also has the same confirmed version of nrfjprog and JLinkARM installed.

Comment: @Bodo Good point. Perhaps OP copied object files from the arm machine too?

Comment: @NikolaiScott The problem is not related to libs installed but your Makefile. Check the answer and modify your Makefile accordingly. Run `make clean` and followed by `make` to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile has hard-coded tool-chains specific to arm. You could tweak it slightly so that it can work on x86:

```
FAMILY := nrf51
SOURCES := main.c uart.c

BUILD_DIR := .build_system
LINKER_SCRIPT := $(BUILD_DIR)/linker_script.ld

arch = $(shell uname -m)

# Intel 64-bit machine?
ifeq ($(arch),x86_64)
CC          := gcc
OBJCOPY     := objcopy
OBJDUMP     := objdump
else
# Default to arm
GNU_PREFIX  := arm-none-eabi
CC          := $(GNU_PREFIX)-gcc
OBJCOPY     := $(GNU_PREFIX)-objcopy
OBJDUMP     := $(GNU_PREFIX)-objdump

# ARM CPU specific
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mfloat-abi=soft
endif

QUIET := @

...
```

Note that I put the CFLAGS inside the condition as well as they are arm specific too.
You can similarly adjust if you want to run on other CPU architectures.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but unfortunately this did not work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @NikolaiScott Just fixed it a bug: `arch = $(shell uname -m)` was missing `-m`. Try again with `make clean` and `make` then.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have fixed my initial error, but now I get


gcc: error: nano.specs: No such file or directory
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 1

or 

gcc: error: nosys.specs: No such file or directory
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 1